# why i have this error Utils is not defined when i want create a chart from chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying reproducing this example from chart.js documentation :

[enter link description here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/animations/progressive-line.html)

But I keep getting this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Utils is not defined

I know it's simple but I can't find out what it is...!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The Utils file is not shipped with the library, its a helper file used so the sample charts are easily to maintain for the chart.js team, it also says in the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.2.1/samples/utils.html) that you should not depend on the file being in this form since its able to change at any moment.

If you really want to use the functions of it you will need to implement them yourself by copying them from the file for example.

Comment: But my code is a copy equal to the original code in the files. I wonder how my chart still has a problem when I copy it.

Comment: First sentence of my answer: `The Utils file is not shipped with the library`

Comment: where can i get utils?

Comment: Did you actually read my answer? The link goes to the file in the documentation and in the last part I litterly said how to get it: `If you really want to use the functions of it you will need to implement them yourself by copying them from the file for example.`

Comment: i'm sorry my english is not good i need to translate your awnsers i didn't undrestand them first now i get it . sorry.